# Simple runscript example with jclouds and clojure (or even just jclouds)

Tags: clojure, jclouds

I have this clojure code

```
(let [group-name "my-test-group"
      compute (compute-service provider user password)
      node (create-node compute group-name)
      node-id (.getId node)]
  (.runScriptOnNode compute node-id ??)
  (destroy-node compute node-id))
```

and I would like to run `ls` on my instance just as an example.  What do I put in the `??` to make that work?

Reading the Jclouds docs it says I'm supposed to put a `Statement` object there but I do not know how to create a statement object for the `ls` command in Clojure or Java.  I'd accept an example in Clojure or Java (as I can easily translate between the two).

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question @Alan.  I'm using jclouds.  `(.runScriptOnNode compute ...)` is equivalent to the java code `compute.runScriptOnNode(...)` and `compute` is an instance of `ComputeService`.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the example at https://jclouds.apache.org/start/compute/ but for the script they just put a variable name called `script` and do not show how to create such a script.  So any script will do (whether it's running `ls`, `echo`, or some other command).  I just need to know how to specify my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `runScriptOnNode` has several forms. As defined in the [ComputeService](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/compute/src/main/java/org/jclouds/compute/ComputeService.java) interface, the script can be provided as a `Statement` object or as a simple String.

If you want to use the `Statement` then you can build it by using the helper methods in the [Statements](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/scriptbuilder/src/main/java/org/jclouds/scriptbuilder/domain/Statements.java) class (something like: `Statements.exec("ls")`), but it is up to you to use the Statement or the String form.

And here are the examples using the two methods (with String and with Statement) assuming the example code from the OP surrounds this code:

```
(.runScriptOnNode compute node-id "ls")
(.runScriptOnNode compute node-id (Statements/exec "ls"))
```